# Spring Web application tymeleaf : POST request directed to wrong address

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have post mapping for URL: "/bank/addnew" My controller looks like:
Upon submission the form is submitted to "http://127.0.0.1:8082/banks/%20/banks" However, I need it to go to "http://127.0.0.1:8082/banks/addnew". Thanks for the Help!

[image: The post request is directed to the wrong url]

```
@Controller
public class BankController {   
    
    @Autowired private BankService bankService;
    
    @GetMapping("/banks")
    public String bankList() {
        return "bank/bank_list";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/banks/addnew")
    public String addNew(Bank bank) {
        bankService.save(bank);
        return "redirect: /banks";
    }
}
```

And my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" th:action="@{/banks/addnew}"  >
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Bank Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" name="name">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>             
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Post Method was actually working okay. I checked it by printing the Model object inside the target controller. However, it was being submitted to the database a NULL value because I didn't initialize getters and setters for my Model. Finally, there was a space in the return string, thus I removed it.

[image: My database]

The controller Should have a return statement with no space.

```
return "redirect:/banks";
```